# Excel Index - how to return a blank if the cells show 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel snip

[image]

In column P I've entered a formala to return the name of the column with the lowest value J to N.

The formula is:

```
=INDEX($J$1:$N$1,MATCH(MIN(J2:N2),J2:N2,0))
```

For row 5 to 9 all the values are zero so I'd like P5 to P9 to return a blank cell. Instead it's returning the name of column J. The values in J to N are formulas multiplying D with (hidden) E to I.

I have tried using various IF functions but I can't get it to work without giving me an error popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something along the lines of using an `IF()` logic

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `P2`

```
=IF(O2=0,"",INDEX($J$1:$N$1,MATCH(O2,J2:N2,0)))
```

---

Alternatively, if you are an `MS365` user then can try using `BYROW()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `P2`

```
=BYROW(J2:N9,LAMBDA(m,IF(MIN(m)=0,"",XLOOKUP(SUM(m),m,$J$1:$N$1))))
```

---

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't even consider using column O. This works perectly

Comment: Sounds Good, glad you got resolved it !!! 